# Como retornar diferentes estruturas em uma função com um valor definido em runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Olá, estou trabalhando em um projeto para Windows que possui uma estrutura(do próprio Windows) que muda conforme a arquitetura do sistema(x86/x64), como retornar a estrutura correta por uma função baseado na informação de qual arquitetura do Windows o usuário está usando?

Por exemplo:

```
struct s_arch_x86
{
    uint32_t    callback0;
    uint32_t    flags;
    uint32_t    callback1;
};

struct s_arch_x64
{
    uint64_t    callback0;
    uint32_t    flags;
    uint32_t    flags2;
    uint64_t    callback1;
};

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
auto get_struct_based_on_arch(uint32_t arch, uintptr_t address)
{
    return arch == 32 ? reinterpret_cast<T1>(address) : reinterpret_cast<T2>(address);
}

get_struct_based_on_os_arch<s_arch_x86*, s_arch_x64*>(get_os_arch(), ptr)->callback1 = 0;
```

No MSVC com C++17 tenho o seguinte erro ao compilar o código acima: `error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'T2' to 'T1'`

Comment: É pra todas essas versões? (não que precise de  nenhuma, provavelmente no pior caso `#ifdef` resolve em todas)

Comment: Não, qualquer uma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que está complicado demais...

A não ser que exista alguma razão para usar templates (eu pelo menos não estou vendo nenhuma) eu faria algo assim:

```
if (get_os_arch() == 32)
{
  s_arch_x86* x86 = (s_arch_x86*)ptr;
  x86->callback1 = 0;
}
else
{
  s_arch_x64* x64 = (s_arch_x64*)ptr;
  x64->callback1 = 0;
}
```

Esse é só um código ilustrativo, nem sei se está totalmente correto, mas o importante, para mim, seria **não** usar aquela complicação de templates...

Encapsulando em uma função:

```
void resetCallback(uintptr_t ptr)
{
  if (get_os_arch() == 32)
  {
    s_arch_x86* x86 = (s_arch_x86*)ptr;
    x86->callback1 = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    s_arch_x64* x64 = (s_arch_x64*)ptr;
    x64->callback1 = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que lotaria o código de condicionais if/else e de blocos

Comment: então é só encapsular em uma função...

Comment: Não é simples assim, essa estrutura muda conforme a arquitetura, versão e build do Windows, é uma estrutura relacionada a windows driver, existe varias builds diferentes no windows 10(10240, 10586, 14393, 15063, 16299, 17134, 17763, 18362, 18363), lotaria o código de if/else if ou switch de qualquer forma, acredito que não tenha uma forma melhor

Comment: como eu disse acima, é só encapsular em uma função para evitar a repetição de if/switch

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui achar o uso pra isso, mas você pode receber por template a arquitetura que quer utilizar.

Link com um exemplo: https://godbolt.org/z/MKWTcV.

```
#include <cstdint>

struct s_arch_x86
{
    uint32_t    callback0;
    uint32_t    flags;
    uint32_t    callback1;
};

struct s_arch_x64
{
    uint64_t    callback0;
    uint32_t    flags;
    uint32_t    flags2;
    uint64_t    callback1;
};

template <typename ARCH>
auto getArchStructure(std::uintptr_t address)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<ARCH*>(address);
}

int main()
{
    auto x32 = getArchStructure<s_arch_x64>(0xFFFFFF);
    auto x64 = getArchStructure<s_arch_x86>(0xFFFFFF);

    x32->callback1 = 0;

    x64->callback1 = 0;

    return 1;
}
```